# INSERT as vezes não inseri todos os dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

estou com um probleminha,

```html
$alta = $_GET['alt-a'];
$altb = $_GET['alt-b'];
$altc = $_GET['alt-c'];
$altd = $_GET['alt-d'];

$correta = $_GET['correta'];
$img = $_SESSION['imagem'];
$questao = $_SESSION['questao'];


$inserta = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO alternativas VALUES ($codigo, '$alta', 'a'), ($codigo, '$altb', 'b'), ($codigo, '$altc', 'c'), ($codigo, '$altd', 'd') ");
$insert = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO questoes VALUES ($codigo, '$questao', '$img', '$correta')");
echo "Questão inserida com sucesso!";
```

Ao executar esse script, em boa parte das vezes ele funciona normal...porem em algumas ele nao inseri todas as informações, em alguns casos ele inseri completamente o $insert, e o $inserta que vao ser inseridas 4 linhas..as vezes so inseri duas, o problema é sempre no $inserta, as vezes não inseri tudo.

Comment: Como é feito o envio desses parâmetros?

Comment: Alguns por GET, outros por SESSION, porem ja coloquei um echo pra fazer o teste dos GET e sempre recebe todos, porem ao gravar no banco as vezes nao vai todos.

Comment: Por acaso o codigo é sua chave primária?

Comment: Esse codigo é o ultimo do auto increment, um Insert insere a questao...pega o codigo do auto increment...e adiciona as alternativas em outra tabela...e leva esse codigo como referencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal Consegui a Solução, o problema era que no banco o campo da tabela alternativas esta com Chave Primaria, e quanto era inserido uma alternativa que ja existia não era gravado o INSERT.

Comment: Marque a sua resposta como correta para encerrar a questão. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei muito bem o que esta dando erro, mas posso indicar uma possivel solucao.
Tenta colocar os campos da tabela que voe esta inserindo na query.... tipo assim.

```
$insert = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO questoes(campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4) VALUES ($codigo, '$questao', '$img', '$correta')");
echo "Questão inserida com sucesso!";
```

Eu sempre coloco os nomes por padrao, e por organizaçao no caso de alguem pegar seu codigo posteriormente, mas caso voce nao coloque pode dar uns erros bobos...experimente colocar nos dois insert, se nao der comenta aqui.
Espero ter colaborado!!!

Comment: Vou tentar, antes tinha colocado cada query dessa separada, so que estava com o mesmo problema, entao resolvi unir todas. so que nao resolveu, o mais engraçado é que o problema acontece em alguns momentos...e fica por um tempo dando erro...depois desaparece e funciona normal..

Comment: Estranho mesmo, mas pode deixar em query juntas mesmo, mas informe os campos da tabela do banco como fiz no exemplo ai...

Comment: Coloquei o nomes, so que continua do mesmo jeito.